# About an SDE problem

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus, ergodic-theory, stochastic-differential-equations, stochastic-pde

I’m now faced with an SDE problem to prove the solution of the SDE:
$$dX_t=(X_t-X_t^3)dt+\sigma dW_t, X_0=0$$
Is ergodic and estimate the bound of $EX_t^4$.
I started to try to solve the SDE to get the explicit solution. Consider $Y_t=f(X_t)$, then we have:

$$dY_t=(f^{\prime}(X_t)(X_t-X_t^3)+\frac{\sigma}{2}f^{\prime\prime}(X_t))dt+\sigma f^\prime(X_t)dW_t$$

When $f^\prime(x)=exp(\frac{x^2}{\sigma}(\frac{x^2}{2}-1))$, we have:

$$dY_t=\sigma f^\prime (X_t)dW_t$$

And I don’t know how to go on now.

Comment: What's the given definition for ergodicity? For your bound apply Ito to $X^{4}$ and estimate cleverly. In any case I highly doubt that there is a closed solution for the equation.

Comment: @Tobsn: For me, I'd take the definition to calculate $\int_0^T X_tdt$ to converge to be the definition. And for the bound, I also do not think there is the sharp estimation. But, whatever, I couldn't even give a bound here... That's why I'm asking this question.

Comment: That for sure is no conventional definition of ergodicity If anything, you should consider the time avergaed integral. A gave you a hint on how to get bounds for your 4th moment.

Comment: @Tobsn :  I didn't totally get your hint, do you mean calculate the Ito differential of $X_t^4$? It may leave a term about $X_t^6$ which I don't know how to estimate.

Comment: the $X^{6}$ will come with a minus term, thus can be dropped in your estimate.

Comment: @Tobsn I’ve thought about it but couldn’t figure out the way. Could you give me some help here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138177/discussion-between-user734979-and-tobsn).

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, to find the bound we can apply Ito to $f=X_{t}^{4}$, which, taking the exptectation and remembering that the stochastic part vanishes, yields:

$$
m(t) = \alpha(t)+\int_{0}^{t}4m(s)ds -4 \int_{0}^{t}\mathbb{E}[X_{s}^{6}] ds
$$
which we can bound from above

$$
m(t) \le \alpha(t)+\int_{0}^{t}4m(s)ds 
$$

where $\alpha(t) = \int_{0}^{t}6 \sigma^2\mathbb{E}[X_{s}^{2}]ds$ and $m(t)= \mathbb{E}[X_{t}^{4}]$.

Since $4$ is a non-decreasing function, by the integral version of Gronwall Lemma we get:

$$
m(t) \le e^{4t} \alpha(t)
$$